# How to sequentially test an Object for validity without eval?

Tags: javascript, object, vue.js

In Vue.js I currently have some v-if conditionals that require a nested value from an object that may or may not have loaded completely on page load. Ideally I need a way to sequentially test the path of an object to prevent errors, so for example if the object is 
`rawData.system.destinations`
then I would like to check the validity of the object sequentially as so
`rawData`=>`rawData.system`=>`rawData.system.destinations`

Currently the rough version is to either use `<template v-if="rawData && rawData.system && rawData.system.destinations">` or a dirty eval method I wrote that takes a string and then tests each part sequentially, however I am aware that eval is still the work of the devil and this code won't see use for that reason.

Hoping that there is a way to solve this without having to write a mass of if conditionals, even happier if there is a better way of doing this in vue all together

Comment: I am also doing it the same way and have always thought about the same. Let's see if someone comes up with a better solution.